# Is there a way to set pseudo styles inline, add nested style tags, or nested styles or properties?

Tags: html, css, svg, stylesheet

In SVG you can do something like this (nested style tag with inline pseudo state):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <!-- nested style tag --> 
    <style type="text/css" >
      <![CDATA[

        circle {
           stroke: #006600;
           fill:   #00cc00;
        }
        circle:hover {
           stroke: #FF6600;
           fill:   #00ccFF;
        }

      ]]>
    </style>

    <circle  cx="40" cy="40" r="24"/>
</svg>
```

Can you do the same for HTML elements somehow, for example, button?

```
<input type="button" value="Button">

    <style type="text/css" >
      <![CDATA[

        this {
           color: #006600;
        }
        this:hover {
           color: #FF6600;
        }

      ]]>
    </style>

</input>
```

Or nested style tags:

```
<input type="button" value="Button">
    <style>
       <color>#006600</color>
    </style>
    <style state="hover">
       <color>#FF6600</color>
    </style>
</input>
```

Or inline pseudo styles:

```
<input type="button" style="color:#000000" style.hover="#ff6600" value="Button"/>
```

I've found other posts on this but they are a few years old. Also, I know about separation of concerns and using external style sheets. This is for a prototyping tool. When the user publishes the CSS will be separated out.

PS. There is a very valid reason to use only inline and not CSS; if you are creating HTML Email News Letters since Gmail now only supports inline styles and strips ID tags and Style blocks

Answer (score 0):

use inline style attribute:

```
<div style="width:20px;height:20px;background-color:#ffcc00;"></div>
```

Comment: I'm interested in inline pseudo styles or inline nested style tags or nodes such as in the SVG example.